# Missing file error in asset:precompline with RAILS_ENV=production, but not development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, spree, bootstrap-sass

Attempting to run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

gives the error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: *.
Load path: /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/stylesheets
```

If I use RAILS_ENV=development everything proceeds normally, no errors.  Why might this be happening?

How can I resolve this?  The app uses Spree 3.x, which includes Bootstrap-SASS

---

**EDIT: I have solved the error, but would like a deeper working understanding of why this worked.**

I solved this by copying application.css to application.css.scss, and removing all content from application.css.

My *guess* is SASS files need to be included from other SASS files for the precomplier to work.  Is that correct?  Is there more to it?  I'll gladly upvote/accept an answer that explains this.

---

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3' 
#gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end


# group :development do
#   gem 'rails-dev-boost', :git => 'git://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost.git' #speed up development
#   gem 'rb-inotify', '>= 0.8.8'
# end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
#gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'spree', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'

gem 'pg'
gem 'spree_i18n', git: 'git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git', branch: '3-0-stable'

gem 'spree_yadav_jewelry', :path => 'extensions/spree_yadav_jewelry'
gem 'spree_yadav_diamonds', :path => 'extensions/spree_yadav_diamonds'

gem 'has_scope'
```

This is the complete error output:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: *.
Load path: /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/stylesheets
(sass):18
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:311:in `visit_import'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:316:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: *.
Load path: /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1/assets/stylesheets
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:65:in `import'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:311:in `visit_import'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.18/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:316:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.3.4/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

application.css looks like this, no changes made from the base setup:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "*"
```

Comment: What does your `application.css` or `application.css.sass` look like? It looks like you are having issues including bootstrap into your stylesheets manifest.

Comment: @MaxAlcala I've added the file contents.  I'm new to Rails, but my understanding was that this default content should import all of the other stylesheets for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by copying application.css to application.css.scss, and removing all content from application.css.